# Invalid conversion for 2d array from function in c++

Tags: c++

I have a 2d array of column size 2 and row size of x. I want to make an insertion sort based on value of 1st column of each row. So if the given array is [[2,3],[4,1],[5,6],[1,6]] My output array will be [[1,6],[2,3],[4,1],[5,6]] . I have written  C++ function for this. But there is a problem when i am trying to return the array. And it is saying "invalid conversion from int (*)[2] to int" . As i am not very experienced in C++ i do not know how to fix this and why this is cause.Here is my function :

```
int* Insertion(int arr[][2],int x)
{
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i;j>0;j--)
        {
            if(arr[j][0]<arr[j-1][0])
            {
                int temp1=arr [j][0];
                int temp2=arr [j][1];
                arr [j][0]=arr[j-1][0];
                arr[j][1]=arr[j-1][1];
                arr[j-1][0]=temp1;
                arr[j-1][1]=temp2;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: please tell me why you are not using references and `std::vector`

Comment: why are you returning arr from this function? you are already changing it as a non const input parameter

Comment: Is vector be a good solution ?? Because the code will be used for a programming challenge and i am considering memory efficiency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> int* Insertion(int arr[][2],int x)
> ```

`arr` is a pointer pointing to some `int[2]`.

That `int[2]` may or may not be the beginning of an entire array of `int[2]`s.

In fact, the function is completely equivalent to:

```
int* Insertion(int (*arr)[2],int x)
```

So the type of `arr` is `int(*)[2]`. And the return type is `int*`. Those two pointer types are not compatible because they point to very different things, hence the error message.

---

An elegant fix would be to use an `auto` return type, so that the return type is the same as the type of `arr` without having to spell out the complicated type again:

```
auto Insertion(int arr[][2],int x) -> decltype(arr)
```

An even more elegant fix would be to **get rid of all this pointer nonsense** and use a `std::vector` of size x*y to store the data. Search Stack Overflow for ideas on how to create a matrix datatype in C++.

Comment: If considering memory effieciency will vector be a good solution ? Thanks by the way :)

Comment: @NazmusSalehin: What kind of problems do you expect? Your current solution also needs to store the array *somewhere*. I suppose it allocates memory from the free store via `new[]`, which is already a bad thing. `std::vector` also allocates from the free store, but it does so safely. If, in contrast, your current array is not dynamic, then you can use `std::array` to achieve the same effect. In any case, don't optimise before you even have a working solution.

Comment: @Nazmus Salehin, use profiler to find performance bottlenecks. and read at least cppreference before asking such questions; that is more efficient way to dive into cpp.

Comment: Thank you. I have told already i am not experienced in c++ and so i think it is possible that those question may arise  and i can ask these here :)

Answer (score 1):

```
using type = int [ 2 ] ;
type * Insertion(int arr[][2],int x) { return arr ; }
```

arr has type "array of int arrays of size 2", which can be converted to a pointer to array of size 2. your function returns a pointer to int.

---

btw, if you want full declaration without aliases, there is a syntax :

```
int ( * Insertion( int arr[][ 2 ] , int x ) )[ 2 ] ;
```